# Is thermal vibration a property of a particle moving back and forth by itself, or of a system of particles colliding?

Tags: temperature, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

When we say gas has a given temperature, it means the particles vibrate, or move back and forth, in the aggregate.

Is this movement back and forth only due to each particle moving linearly and then colliding with other particles, which changes its path to a different one, so that over time the particle is moving "back and forth" due to the collisions?

Or is it the case that individual particles move back and forth even by themselves, and *on top of that* they also collide with other particles?

So if we look at the motion of a particle in-between times when it collides with other particles, does it move in a single direction at constant speed, or will it anyway be moving left/right, up/down randomly even on its own?

So if we remove all other particles but one in a container, will it have entirely linear paths until it collides with the walls of its container? Or will it vibrate back/forth even as it primarily moves in one direction in the container?

Pretty much the difference between these two images:

[image: two particle paths]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you model the particles in the gas. In classical mechanics, simple point like particles should follow Newton’s laws: an object traveling at some velocity will continue to travel like that unless acted on by an external force. In other words, it would move in a straight line without any rotation or “wiggles” until it hits another particle or the wall. If you modeled the particle as a sphere, then you could let it rotate. If each molecule had two atoms, you could let these atoms be connected like two balls on a spring which could oscillate back and forth.

Atoms are pretty small, so you need Quantum Mechanics if you want to actually get into the weeds here.